# Android animations and screen rotation

Tags: android, android-animation

I have animated some properties with AnimatorSet (simple fade-in, fade-out etc.) but when I change the screen rotation my activity always goes back to its starting layout. Is there something I'm missing here?

```
ObjectAnimator fadeOut = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(loginBtn, "alpha", 1f, 0f);
    fadeOut.setDuration(300);
    ObjectAnimator fadeIn = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(backBtn, "alpha", 0f, 1f);
    fadeIn.setDuration(300);
    final AnimatorSet mAnimationSet = new AnimatorSet();
    mAnimationSet.play(fadeOut).with(fadeIn);
    mAnimationSet.start();
```

Comment: What do you mean? Do you need animation while rotating the screen.?

Comment: I mean I want to keep the state I have animated to afterwards. When I turn my device, the layout goes back to what it was before the animation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use these code in the yours manifest file(in the yours activity class) than data will not change in the both mode of the mobile(landscape or portrait)

```
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenSize|screenLayout|uiMod
```

OR USE SIMPLY THESE

```
android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|screenLayout"
```